# Im new to coding and pardon me if my question is dumb but may i know how do I find the total marks for the test for each student?

Tags: python-3.x, int, nested-loops

```
students=int(input('How many students do you have?'))
tests=int(input('How many test for your module?'))
for i in range(students):
    i=i + 1
    print('******* Student # {:0d} *******'.format(i))
    while tests>0:
        for t in range(tests):
            t=t+1
            total=int(input('test number {:0d}:'.format(t)))
        break
    average = total/tests
    print('the average for student # {:0.0f} is {:0.1f}'.format(i,average))
```

As you can see,im having a problem from getting the average as the total only takes the final test marks and not the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the marks:

```
total = 0
for t in range(tests):
    # note the += instead of the =
    # this adds the new mark instead of overwriting the old one
    total += int(input('test number {:0d}:'.format(t+1)))
```

---

**some small Improvements**

don't increment the value while iterating over it

```
i=i + 1
```

instead add 1 to all outputs or change the range to iterate over

---

remove the unnecessary while loop

```
while tests>0:
    break
```

a for-loop for 0 values ends itself automatically